# Place Lightbox close button on top right area

Tags: css, lightbox2

How can I do this? Mine appears in the bottom right side. I am using Lightbox v2.7.1.

Comment: Please add jfiddle - there's no way to help you if you don't add legit code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacement code for v2.8.1.
This will move both close button and caption to the top.

```
Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
var self = this;
$('<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to move the data container above the outer container. Replace the code beginning on line 59 of the lightbox.js file with this:

```
Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
  var self = this;
  $("<div class='lb-dataContainer'><div class='lb-data'><div class='lb-details'><span class='lb-caption'></span><span class='lb-number'></span></div><div class='lb-closeContainer'><a class='lb-close'></a></div></div></div></div><div id='lightboxOverlay' class='lightboxOverlay'></div><div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'><div class='lb-outerContainer'><div class='lb-container'><img class='lb-image' src='' /><div class='lb-nav'><a class='lb-prev' href='' ></a><a class='lb-next' href='' ></a></div><div class='lb-loader'><a class='lb-cancel'></a></div></div></div>").appendTo($('body'));
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and best approach, that is just some CSS rules and don't change the original lib (which is the best choice for maintenance issues) would might look like this:

Shall we use flexbox to our advantage? Yes, Lets go!

(obs: this is SCSS code)

```
#lightbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    .lb-dataContainer {
        order: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        //Want to hide the text? no problem
        .lb-details {
            opacity: 0;
        }

        // Want to change the icon? no problem too.
        .lb-close {
            background: url(../images/ico/close.png);
            background-size: contain;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right;
        }
    }

    .lb-outerContainer{
        order: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works aces in 2021, I guess you should specify it is not css but needs to be compiled :)

Comment: Yess! It's soo usual to me that i forgot to explain that is SCSS code! thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is working code for v2.7.1. Replace the code beginning on line 59 of the lightbox.js file with this:

```
Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
var self = this;
$("<div id='lightboxOverlay' class='lightboxOverlay'></div><div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'><div class='lb-dataContainer'><div class='lb-data'><div class='lb-details'><span class='lb-caption'></span><span class='lb-number'></span></div><div class='lb-closeContainer'><a class='lb-close'></a></div></div></div><div class='lb-outerContainer'><div class='lb-container'><img class='lb-image' src='' /><div class='lb-nav'><a class='lb-prev' href='' ></a><a class='lb-next' href='' ></a></div><div class='lb-loader'><a class='lb-cancel'></a></div></div></div></div>").appendTo($('body'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers from APAD1 and user1999659, I did the following to make the close button go up-right corner, but keep the caption below the image.

This is working code for v2.7.1. Replace the code beginning on line 59 of the lightbox.js file with this:

```
Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
  var self = this;
  $("<div id='lightboxOverlay' class='lightboxOverlay'></div><div id='lightbox' class='lightbox'><div class='lb-dataContainer'><div class='lb-data'><div class='lb-details'><span class='lb-number'></span></div><div class='lb-closeContainer'><a class='lb-close'></a></div></div></div><div class='lb-outerContainer'><div class='lb-container'><img class='lb-image' src='' /><div class='lb-nav'><a class='lb-prev' href='' ></a><a class='lb-next' href='' ></a></div><div class='lb-loader'><a class='lb-cancel'></a></div></div></div><div class='lb-dataContainer'><div class='lb-data'><div class='lb-details'><span class='lb-caption'></span></div></div></div></div>").appendTo($('body'));      
  $('.lb-data .lb-details').css('width', '100%');
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I edited code like here (moved close block to other Div):

```
Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
var self = this;
$('<div id="lightboxOverlay" class="lightboxOverlay"></div><div id="lightbox" class="lightbox"><div class="lb-outerContainer"><div class="lb-closeContainer"><a class="lb-close"></a></div><div class="lb-container"><img class="lb-image" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" /><div class="lb-nav"><a class="lb-prev" href="" ></a><a class="lb-next" href="" ></a></div><div class="lb-loader"><a class="lb-cancel"></a></div></div></div><div class="lb-dataContainer"><div class="lb-data"><div class="lb-details"><span class="lb-caption"></span><span class="lb-number"></span></div></div></div></div>').appendTo($('body'));
```

And added following CSS

```
.lb-closeContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -28px;
}
```

And this CSS some edited

```
.lb-closeContainer .lb-close {
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url(../images/close.png) top right no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  text-align: right;
  outline: none;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=70);
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

.lb-closeContainer .lb-close:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuYQ9.png

Answer (score 0):

I took the code from Vitor Régis which is scss and converted it to css for those who don't have a compiler. This definitely the best option since it doesn't require modifying the source code at all.

```
#lightbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#lightbox .lb-dataContainer {
    order: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#lightbox .lb-dataContainer .lb-details {
    opacity: 0;
}

#lightbox .lb-dataContainer .lb-close {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

#lightbox .lb-outerContainer{
    order: 1;
}
```